# REGEXP to check for double letters at certain positions in mariadb?

Tags: regex, string, mariadb

I need to find all strings containing double letters in positions from 4th to 10th inclusive.

I can find all double letters by

```
'([a-zA-Z])\1{1,3}';
```

and positions by

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(columnmame, 4, 9 ) FROM table;
```

but I do not know how to combine them?

so that the following examples are found:

```
Liverpool;
Sheffield Central.
```

but not

```
Arran.
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky on MariaDB, because it does not support backreferences such as `\1` etc.  One trick we can do is to do use a `LIKE` expression on a substring of the column from positions 4 to 10 inclusive.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, SUBSTRING(columnmame, 4, 9) AS c
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE c LIKE '%aa%' OR c LIKE '%bb%' OR c LIKE '%dd%' OR
      -- rest of alphabet here
      c LIKE '%xx%' OR c LIKE '%yy%' OR c LIKE '%zz%';
```

Comment: yes, I am trying something like ([a-z]{2}) for repeating characters ...listing all  letters is laborious.

Comment: You _can't_ express `([a-z])\1` using MariaDB's regex engine. Give up.  My method is reasonable.